# Cannot enable VT-d on Lenovo ideapad 700-15ISK

Tags: virtualbox, lenovo, virtualization

I am trying to use virtualbox on my Lenovo [ideapad 700-15ISK](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/ideapad-700-series/Yoga-S730/p/88YGS701077) with Kubuntu 19.10. (CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) [i5-6300HQ](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88959/intel-core-i5-6300hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-20-ghz.html) @ 2.30GHz)

When i try to start any x64 image in virtualbox, it fails with the error message `VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes`, even though it is enabled in the bios and `lscpu` shows `Virtualization: VT-x`.

Googling around a bit, i found that it is not VT-x that seems to be the problem here, but VT-d, and it seems that this is indeed disabled (`dmesg | grep -iE DMAR` gives no output), but there is no separate option in the bios for VT-d, only an option `Intel Virtual Technology`, which appears to only enable VT-x.

Now, i can't find official information on which chipset this device has, but [this](https://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-ideapad-700-15isk-15-6-core-i5-6300hq-8-gb-ram-1-tb-hdd-us/) claims it is Mobile Intel HM170, which according to [ark.intel.com](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/90584/mobile-intel-hm170-chipset.html), does have VT-d.

Is there any way to enable VT-d? Am i missing a kernel parameter? I tried adding `intel_iommu=on`, which did not change anything (except for showing `DMAR: IOMMU enabled` in dmesg). I've found some outdated information where people added extra kernel modules/parameters, but this seemed not applicable to my situation.

Comment: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88959/intel-core-i5-6300hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-20-ghz.html confirms that CPU is capable of VT-d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been an issue with the BIOS. I updated it (using fwupdtools and an extracted UEFI capsule from [the official BIOS update for windows](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/700-series/700-15isk/downloads/ds111737)), and now it just works.

Comment: Glad to hear it's fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You generally enable and disable CPU features like these in the BIOS. How you go about doing so will depend on your own BIOS version, so you should look at the BIOS instructions for your computer.

If virtualisation is enabled in the bios, it would be worth checking that the guests are configured to take advantage of it: What settings are you using in your guest?

If you are allocating more than 3GB of RAM, you'll need to enable PAE/NX for your guest. From all I can gather, VT-d is only required for hardware passthrough.

Comment: (Edited question to clarify) There is only an option for "Intel Virtual Technology", which toggles VT-x, but no separate option for VT-d.

Comment: Hey @deltragon, I've added a bit more info to the answer. Has your guest got PAE/NX enabled, and how much RAM have you allocated to it?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, PAE/NX is enabled on the guest, and i am allocating 4GB of RAM. Disabling VT-x on the guest just gives me a warning that 64bit guests require VT-x and might not boot, and then the guest just blackscreens.